# How to find a cell with a specific value across the entire sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I apologize if this has been asked before. I did my research and nothing I found seemed to be able to answer my question though, but if I missed something, please do point me to it. I have searched Google and this site specifically, but it's always possible I wasn't using the right words.

I am trying to get the column reference based on where the cell matching a specific value is. Using `INDEX` and `MATCH` together, I am able to get the row that I want, but I have not been able to find a formula to properly get the column.

"g" is in cell A2 on this sheet.

Current Result:
[image: Error]

Expected Result:
[image: Expected]

And located at (2,2), or `C3`, in this sheet.
Table being searched:
[image]

Any solution that gets either the true column or the value of the first cell in the column would be helpful.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zrgwmlIrwFh7KgWg0MbcIRksdFknvCdygGzNMvUBEGk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You might think about changing the title of the question to something more like "How to find a cell with a specific value across the entire sheet" to make it easier for others to find that question.

Comment: @Maciek okay, will do. I struggled with the title, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the current solution is that HLOOKUP only searches the first row.
The formula to solve this problem will not be so simple.

[Here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/36857767?hl=en) you can find very similar problem.

I took formula from there and changed it a little.

To get the column number you need this:

```
 ={
  INDEX(FILTER(
    table!$A:$F,
    ARRAYFORMULA(SEARCH("h", QUERY(table!$A:$F,,99^99))
    )),1,1)
}
```

To get the row number use this:

```
={
 INDEX(FILTER(
   table!$A:$F,
   ARRAYFORMULA(SEARCH("h", QUERY(TRANSPOSE(table!$A:$F),,99^99))
   )),1,1)
}
```

Change "h" to a different value or cell reference if needed.